# Graph Terminology: What is an ancestral path?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

**Shortest ancestral path:** An ancestral path between two vertices v and w in a digraph is a directed path from v to a common ancestor x, together with a directed path from w to the same ancestor x. A shortest ancestral path is an ancestral path of minimum total length. We refer to the common ancestor in a shortest ancestral path as a shortest common ancestor. Note also that an ancestral path is a path, but not a directed path.

[image]

I am quite confused by this description for two reasons.

First, what does the sentence - "An ancestral path between two vertices v and w in a digraph is a directed path from v to a common ancestor x, together with a directed path from w to the same ancestor x" - mean because there is no directed path from v to w since the path to the ancestor from v is in the "opposite direction" of the path to the ancestor from w. What I mean is in the picture to the left, it's claimed that the shortest ancestral path is 3-1-5-9-10 but this doesn't make sense because we can't do 1-5 since that direction doesn't exist. It seems that they combined the directed path from v to the ancestor with the directed path from w to the ancestor in the opposite direction, essentially treating the path as undirected.

Second, and relatedly, the first sentence says that an ancestral path is a "directed path" but the last sentence says "Note also that an ancestral path is a path, but not a directed path."

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> An ancestral path between two vertices $v$ and $w$ in a digraph is a directed path from $v$ to a common ancestor $x$, together with a directed path from $w$ to the same ancestor $x$.

is not saying that an ancestral path is a directed path. It's saying that an ancestral path is made up of two pieces. One piece is a directed path from $v$ to $x$. The other piece is a directed path from $w$ to $x$.

If we ignore the orientations, and allow our paths to backtrack, then we can combine the first directed path with the *reverse* of the second, and get an undirected path. This is what the sentence

> Note also that an ancestral path is a path, but not a directed path.

is saying.

Not everyone's definitions allow a path to repeat edges (or vertices), but maybe the source you're consulting does. In any case, when we take a *shortest ancestral path*, there will be no repetition, so this will be a path (undirected path) by anyone's definition.

Comment: Thank you so very much!